# Date Time Array Sort

Tags: vb.net

I have an array which has date objects which i need to sort in ascending or descending order as per date i.e latest one first(date can also contain timestamp).

Comment: sorry for the mistake,I needed the answer in VB.net as i am newbie to vb.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.Sort(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) with a custom `IComparer(Of T)` delegate should work:

```
Dim dates = {Date.Now, Date.Now.AddDays(1), Date.Now.AddDays(2)}
Array.Sort(Of Date)(dates, Function(d1, d2) d2.CompareTo(d1))
```

> I have sorted the date.But i have an array with objects which contains
>   date object as a member.So how do i sort the array of objects which
>   contain date object?

You can again use the custom `Sort` delegate(assuming the *object* is a class `Person`):

```
Array.Sort(Of Person)(persons, Function(p1, p2) p2.BirthDate.CompareTo(p1.BirthDate))
```

But the most readable way is using Linq:

```
Dim orderedPersons = From p In persons
                     Order By p.BirthDate Descending
For Each p In orderedPersons
    Console.WriteLine("{0}'s birtdate is at {1}", p.Name, p.BirthDate)
Next
```

If you need a List from the query use `.ToList()`, if you need an `array` use `.ToArray()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,I have sorted the date.But i have an array with objects which contains date object as a member.So how do i sort the array of objects which contain date object?

Comment: what's the order of sorting? or how do I change it?

Comment: @shyamnathan: can you  give a little bit more detail on that?

Comment: in "Array.Sort" ascending or descending order and "p2.BirthDate" can be system.DateTime